# phplist not working

Tags: php, phplist

I have downloaded phplist-2.10.19 and installed  on my server. After all configurations settings has been done. It is working fine on main url.

Like : http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/phplist/public_html/lists/

But when I tried to include this fine in another file then it's showing me the following error:

> Error, cannot find config file

Following is the code of that file.

```
<html>
<title>Test</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once('../phplist/public_html/lists/index.php');?>
</body></html>
```

Why is it happening like that?

Comment: What have you done to try to debug this? Have you looked at the index.php file to try and determine where it is looking for the config file? (lines 14-26). Have you tried `echo`ing out values? You may need to modify the file since you're including it from a different working directory

Comment: I have used echo to check if the control is coming on index.php or not. Otherwise there is a code to check if config file is there or not and this phplist code is not able to find it i think that's why it's showing this error. I can remove this error by providing absolute path of config file but then another error occurs and it goes on..So i just wanna know the root cause for that.

Comment: The root cause looks like it is not made to do what you are trying to do. The include paths to some needed files are made relative (such as config) rather than full. Your best bet would be to go to the PHPList devs/community to see if you can do this or track down and fix the relative paths.

Comment: Yep it's not fulfilling the condition on line 20 of index.php that's why error is there.

Comment: @UnholyRanger : yep, I had also created a new topic for that on phplist forum. http://forums.phplist.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=38909

Answer (score -1):

you may try this code.

```
<html>
<title>Test</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once('phplist/public_html/lists/index.php');?>
</body></html>
```